# Why did Git throw "Failed to load library 'libcurl-4.dll'" while cloning?

Tags: git, github

I was cloning my *private* GitHub repository to a local repository, but Git threw an **error**:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Charley2012/CHMS.git D:\homes\charley\编程\编程\C\CHMS\CHMS.git
Cloning into 'D:\homes\charley\编程\编程\C\CHMS\CHMS.git'...
fatal: failed to load library 'libcurl-4.dll'
```

I have used `cmd.exe` and `Git Bash`, but they both threw the same error message above.
I have reinstalled Git but that does not make any difference.
I have tried to clone other GitHub repositories but I got the same error message.
GitHub Desktop cloned the repository **successfully**, but I don't know why.

I think the problem was caused by a local reason.

I am using Windows 10 and Git 2.41.0.
The files of Git (e.g.`git.exe`) is under `D:\homes\charley\编程\编程\DevTools\Git\cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is me answering my own question, after reinstalling Git to a different directory, the problem was solved.

I found out that the cause of the problem was that the directory that Git was under was `D:\homes\charley\编程\编程\DevTools\`, and that directory contain Chinese characters "编程". The new directory of Git is `S:\Charley\DevTools\`, a directory that doesn't contain special characters.

The command line message of the cloning:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Charley2012/CHMS.git E:\charley\编程\编程\C\CHMS\CHMS.git
Cloning into 'E:\charley\编程\编程\C\CHMS\CHMS.git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
Updating files: 100% (3/3), done.
```

*In my opinion,* because the directory of Git contain Chinese characters, Git can't access `libcurl-4.dll` correctly because of problem converting UTF-8 characters to GBK (GB2312), or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

1. Download `libcurl-4.dll` **here:** https://www.dll-files.com/search/?q=libcurl-4.dll.
2. Put this file in **`[C :\Windows\SysWOW64]`**.
3. Reinstall Git.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think it's probably caused by another reason.

Comment: What about the result? Did it work for you?